# OnBoard Device Debugging with Nokia Asha (SDK 1.1+) in NetBeans

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, java-me, nokia

I was wondering if anybody had any success with the **on-board debugger** when working with Nokia **Asha**.

By this I mean being able to compile the app from Netbeans and see it run on the phone in one step. It is one of the run options within Netbeans, but when it's selected and ran, a Nokia splash screen for OnBoard Device Debugger pops up and the console outputs "Connection refused" and nothing happens, on the phone or on the PC.

And here is my debugger output:

> Attaching to localhost:53773
>   Connection refused.

From Nokia's official SDK documentation "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447863/nokia-asha-on-device-debugger-on-netbeans" they say you should transfer the JAR files manually and execute them on the phone (but this seems quite deprecated to me since they include an onboard debugger with their SDK).

Can anyone share how they made this work? Or any workflow tips for working with Asha?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You have to start up the debugger manually FIRST before you start debugging in Netbeans. Afterwards navigate to the app under settings and "enable debugging" then find the phone's IP address and enter it into the On device debugger application on your computer. Debugging should begin